# Integration and the area between curves

Tags: integration

Find the area enclosed by the curves $y = x^2$ and $x = y^2$.

I'm not sure where to go with this. Neither graph cuts through an axis. Do I change the subject of 1 graph? What do I use as a maximum or minimum when I integrate? I need help and some working to show what I need to do.

Comment: Hint: graph both functions, especially near the origin.

Answer (score 2):

The curves intersect twice: at $(0,0)$ and at $(1,1)$. For each $x\in[0,1]$, $y$ takes values between $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$. So, the area that you're after is equal to$$\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt x}1\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1(\sqrt x-x^2\,)\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The graph of the two functions 
helps to recognize the area of interest 
as a simple difference of the two areas
under the two given curves, 
which is equivalent to the difference 
of two corresponding integrals:

\begin{align} 
A&=
\int_0^1 f_1(x)\,dx
-\int_0^1 f_2(x)\,dx
=
\int_0^1 f_1(x)-f_2(x)\,dx
=\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}
-x^2\,dx 
\\
&=\left(\tfrac23\,x^{\tfrac32}
-\tfrac13\,x^3\right)_{x=0}^{x=1}
=\tfrac13
.
\end{align}